# How to call a jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    function _canvasScrollbar(c, s) {
        ...
    }

    _canvasScrollbar.prototype.myFunction = function(){
        console.log("Yey!");
    };

    $.fn.canvasScrollbar = function (s) {
        var a = {
            handleColor: "#ccc",
            scroll: 'horizontal',
            sliderColor: "#eee"
        };
        $.extend(a, s);
        return this.each(function () {
            new _canvasScrollbar(this, a)
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I initialize it like so:

```
var sc = $(".myDiv").canvasScrollbar();
```

But, how do I call the function `myFunction` once the plugin has been initialized?

p.s. I have tried `$(".myDiv").canvasScrollbar("myFunction")` and `sc.myFunction()`, but neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the new `_canvasScrollbar` instance somewhere. The easiest way to do it with jQuery is using the `data` method.

```
return this.each(function () {
    $(this).data('scrollbar', new _canvasScrollbar(this, a));
})
```

Now you can access your instance using `data` method. And then call the function.

```
sc.data('scrollbar').myFunction();
// Yey!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two type of jQuery 'plugins': `plugins`, which are usually stateless, and `widgets`. You seem to be wanting a `widget`, but you're creating it as a `plugin`. See:

> While most existing jQuery plugins are stateless – that is, we call
>   them on an element and that is the extent of our interaction with the
>   plugin – there's a large set of functionality that doesn't fit into
>   the basic plugin pattern.
>
> In order to fill this gap, jQuery UI has implemented a more advanced
>   plugin system. The new system manages state, allows multiple functions
>   to be exposed via a single plugin, and provides various extension
>   points. This system is called the Widget Factory and is exposed as
>   jQuery.widget as part of jQuery UI 1.8; however, it can be used
>   independently of jQuery UI.

Here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/

To create a widget, you can do it like this:

```js
$.widget('customWidget.canvasScrollbar', {
  options: {
    handleColor: "#ccc",
    scroll: 'horizontal',
    sliderColor: "#eee"
  },

  _create: function() {

  },
  myFunction: function() {
    console.log("Yey!");
  }
});

var sc = $("div").canvasScrollbar();
sc.canvasScrollbar('myFunction')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

This way you have access to other features, such as `sc.canvasScrollbar('instance')`, option setting, etc.

See: https://jqueryui.com/widget/

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `pluginName` variable :  `"canvasScrollbar"` ; setiing `_canvasScrollbar.prototype.myFunction` , `this` at `a` ; defining `settings` object as result of `$.extend()` ; setting `c` `.data(pluginName)` with `s` object within `_canvasScrollbar`; returning `this.element` from `myFunction` for chaining jQuery methods to ;  call `_canvasScrollbar.prototype.myFunction` using `.data(pluginName)` with dot notation `$("div").canvasScrollbar().data("canvasScrollbar").myFunction()`

```js
(function ($) {
    var pluginName = "canvasScrollbar";
  
    function _canvasScrollbar(c, s) {
        $(c).data(pluginName, s)
        return c
    }

    _canvasScrollbar.prototype.myFunction = function(){
        console.log("Yey!");
        // return `this.element` : `this` for chaining jQuery
        // methods to `$(element).data("options").myFunction()`
        return this.element
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (s) {
        var a = {
            handleColor: "#ccc",
            scroll: "horizontal",
            sliderColor: "#eee",
            // set `myFunction` as property of `a`:`settings`
            myFunction: _canvasScrollbar.prototype.myFunction,
            // set `element` as `this`
            element: this
        };
        var settings = $.extend(a, s);
        return this.each(function () {
            new _canvasScrollbar(this, settings)
        })
    }
})(jQuery);

$("div").canvasScrollbar().data("canvasScrollbar").myFunction().css("color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
```